# Share interfaces between API and frontend

Tags: angular, git, typescript, nestjs

I am developing both sides. An API is in nest.js and frontend in Angular. Both sides uses typescript and I am facing problem of sharing interfaces, that should be same. For example ILoginRequest and ILoginResponse. I want to have both projects in separate GIT Repositories. Should I use GIT submodule with 3rd shared GIT repo or somehow create shared npm package or is there some good tool to generate classes automatically (from swagger definition) into frontend or anything else?

EDIT: to generate code for client from swagger, look at [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator)

Comment: Creating an npm package would be the easiest way. All you need is your interfaces and a package.json in order to publish it.

Comment: Anyone coming across this now, might want to consider [tRPC](https://trpc.io/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

NOTE: I have recently stumbled upon [typeorm-entitysharer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm-entitysharer) which "can be used to create client/server classes based on the same TypeORM entities, allowing you to share them." It gives you more control over what you want to share, you can take a look at their example. I didn't opt to use it because it's kind of overkill for me I guess. However, this is how I structured my last project:

---

I have my frontend and backend in one repository, but I guess you could have them separate, but you would still need to keep them next to each other somehow. The file structure would be something like this:

```
workspace
  ├─backend        <- repo #1
  │   ├─src
  │   │   ├─shared <- shared code goes here
  │   │   └─proxy.ts
  │   └─tsconfig.json
  └─frontend       <- repo #2
      ├─src
      │   └─proxy.ts
      └─tsconfig.json
```

Then in `backend/tsconfig.json` you introduce

```
{
    ...
    "paths": {
        "@shared/*": [ "src/shared/*" ],
    }
}
```

and in `frontend/tsconfig.json` you introduce

```
{
    ...
    "paths": {
        "@shared/*": [ "../backend/src/shared/*" ],

        // if you're using TypeORM, this package has dummy decorators
        "typeorm": [ "node_modules/typeorm/typeorm-model-shim.js" ]
        // you can do the same for other packages, point them to dummy paths

        // altirnatively you can route the shared imports through the proxy.ts
        // and replace them in frontend/src/proxy.ts with dummy ones
    }
}
```

*also* don't forget to `npm i typeorm` in your frontend.

#### Example

Let's say I have this in `backend/src/shared/user.entity.ts`

```
import { PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from 'typeorm';

export class UserEntity
{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() id: number;
    @Column() name: string;
    @Column() password: string;
}
```

Now, I can use it anywhere like this:

```
import { UserEntity } from '@shared/model/user.entity';
```

In backend, it's obvious, and in frontend, `@shared/model/user.entity` gets mapped to `../backend/src/shared/model/user.entity`, and the `import from 'typeorm'` inside the entity gets mapped to dummy package.

Comment: Thx for this, for me this is the way to go without the need to maintain a repo just with the entities

Comment: hey Peter Dub, can you mark this as an answer?

Comment: What we have here to my mind pretty much a monorepo check out https://nx.dev/ for a really great tool set for managing mongo repos

Answer (score 3):

Having faced the same problem and looked at a few alternatives.  Here's what I considered and what I choose:

1. Separating the entity definitions into a separate code base - potentially in a different git repo. The problem here is that Nest uses decorators that Angular doesn't understand. That would mean I'd have to include Nest as a dependency which seems like a bad idea or create stub decorators - a waste of time. Rejected
2. Creating a node package - same problems as #1. Rejected
3. Copy paste.  Both the backend and frontend projects have an entity folder.  The backend's entities are *classes* that are decorated with TypeORM decorators (for me).  I copy them to the frontend's entity directory and convert them to *interfaces* because what you get back from the httpclient library (objects that should conform to the interface - not class instances). Adopted

Finally, looking at the comments, I don't see how GraphQL helps here since you aren't attempting to leverage an existing interface - looking to hear from someone on that :)

Comment: Regarding graphql: You can create (and update) frontend type definitions with a script from a running server. This is an easy way to (semi)automatically share type definitions between repos while still having full control and lose coupling. Have a look at apollo schema:download & apollo client:codegen

Comment: I'm not sure how option 3 can work, when it's two different repositories?

Comment: How about using monorepo (e.g. Yarn workspaces, lerna) for sharing

Answer (score 3):

After wasting a full day trying to get this working, I came across [NX/NRWL](https://nx.dev/angular/fundamentals/build-full-stack-applications).

It's basically just a CLI with tools to help structure your app properly. I was able to get it working properly in about an hour. Shared interfaces in a mono-repo is the way to go.

Comment: Link no longer works; here is the best I could find https://nx.dev/getting-started/nx-and-angular